# Swift vs Objcective-C protocols

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

<s>Coming from an Objective-C background where every protocol must always have a delegate property. In Swift that doesn't seem to be the case and it's breaking the paradigm I have had about protocols.</s>

AFAIK in Swift, protocols are used for 2 major purposes: delegation pattern (which would need a delegate like Objective-C) and also composition pattern (that didn't exist in Objective-C and doesn't need a delegate property) coupled with extension making it more effective than the traditional inheritance pattern in Objective-C.

Have I understood correctly? Can you please clarify?

**EDIT:**

What I mean by what I see different is:
From Apple's [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/)

The traditional way is (Slide76):

```
class Ordered {
 func precedes(other: Ordered) -> Bool { fatalError("implement me!") }
}
class Number : Ordered {
 var value: Double = 0
 override func precedes(other: Ordered) -> Bool {
 return self.value < (other as! Number).value
 }
}
```

The new Swift way is (Slide 90):

```
protocol Ordered {
 func precedes(other: Self) -> Bool
}
struct Number : Ordered {
 var value: Double = 0
 func precedes(other: Number) -> Bool {
 return self.value < other.value
 }
}
```

And I have never seen Protocols being used like this in Objective-C. So how are they different?

Comment: *"... where every protocol must always have a delegate property"* – No.

Comment: You have some very incorrect assumptions. In Objective-C, you do not need a delegate property for every protocol.

Comment: Also, every single class with one or more properties is using the composition pattern. This has nothing to do with the programming language. And protocols have nothing to do with the composition pattern (in any language).

Comment: @rmaddy Ohhk, I didn't know that. So where in Objective-C you don't need a delegate property for your protocols? I mean every time that I have used tableView or collectionView, or I created my own custom protocol, I had to say something like `tableView.delegate= self` a delegate property so that the 2 classes could speak together using the delegate. And I find that less and less in Swift.

Comment: The delegation pattern is implemented with protocols. But that doesn't mean that just because you create a protocol there must be a delegate. In other words, protocols have uses other than the delegation pattern.

Comment: @rmaddy like what? you mean like `NSCopying` or `NSCoding`? But aside from this and all the things I got wrong, can you please write an answer about how they are actually different?

Comment: This really seems more like a debating kind of "question".

Comment: @rmaddy I reconstructed my question all over again, should I just close this question and write a new one or keep this highly edited version?

Comment: @asma22 If you read my answer, you'll see that I've answered even your edited version of the question. The "difference" between Objective-C and Swift here is merely that protocols can apply to structs, so you're not forced to use subclassing to solve the problem.

Comment: After a year: I must admit that the entirety of this question was due the lack of proper understanding of Protocols and OOP itself and jumping too quick to Protocol Oriented in Swift...I should have taken it slowly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both in Objective-C and in Swift, protocols have exactly one purpose: to allow arbitrary or unrelated types to be guaranteed of having certain members (or, in the case of optional members, of at least possibly having those members). In particular, this guarantee is important *to the compiler*. Basically, then, a protocol is a sort of pseudo-type that overlays the real type structure and unites it in new ways (instead of, say, the "mixin" employed for the same purpose by some other languages; Ruby, for example, doesn't need protocols because it has modules).

For example, a Bird and an Insect may be unrelated classes, or even (in Swift) not classes at all, but if they both adopt the Flier protocol which requires a `fly()` method, the compiler knows that they can both fly, and will allow the `fly()` message to be sent to a Bird or an Insect.

The fact that protocols can be used in various common and important architectural patterns, such as delegation, is a purely secondary but very natural consequence of the nature of protocols.

Comment: so Swift protocols are no different that Objective-C?

Comment: Basically a protocol is a protocol. Swift protocols are modeled on Objective-C protocols. They are more powerful, though, because you can have protocol extensions, and because they can be adopted by structs and enums, which have no other way of expressing a hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Protocols in Swift can have implementation without an object (in a protocol extension). They can also be extended. There's also obviously anything that you can do with generics in Swift that couldn't be done in Objective C.

So for instance the Indexable protocol could be extended to have a function that returned the index range length which might only apply if the index is an `Int` like this:

```
extension Indexable where Self.Index == Int
{
  func length () -> Int
  {
     return endIndex - startIndex
  }
}
```

(Hopefully I'm remembering my Swift syntax correctly!)

Comment: Can you please give an example of implementation without an object?

Comment: There's a fab WWDC video on Swift protocol stuff https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: I already saw that video, but I was only able to grasp some parts of it. Which part you are referring to? Do you mind editing your answer with a sample code?